# Good reference for values of Ramsey Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, ramsey-theory

I want to know values of Ramsey Numbers $R(4, 4, \ldots, 4; r)$ for $r \geq 2$, where $4$ is repeated $r$ times. It is defined to be the least $n$ such that any complete graph $K_{n}$ colored in $r$-colors a monochromatic $K_{4}$.

I googled a lot and found out that $R(4, 4; 2) = 18$. I would like to know values of $R(4, 4, 4; 3)$ and $R(4, 4, 4, 4; 4)$. Are these values known? The textbook I own on combinatorics is old and does not seem to provide reference on these numbers.

I would be grateful if someone could provide me a reference to some resource that has Ramsey numbers listed (of course, ones that are known).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Small Ramsey Numbers" by Stanisław Radziszowski

https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS1

Comment: Thank you so much. You (MSE overall) is so awesome. I would never have landed at this link all by myself.